# Converter not setting value when state_saving_method is set to client

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am facing a wierd problem where when the beans are viewscoped. The converter is not setting the values to the specified type when the state_saving_method is set to client. It works perfectly when it is set to "server" and also works fine if the beans are requestscoped and set to "client"

The web page looks like this.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{managedBeanState.selectedFoo}" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{managedBean.foos)" var="foo" itemLabel="#{foo.name} " itemValue="#{foo}" />
    <f:converter converterId="fooConverter" />
    <p:ajax update="whom" onstart="menuStart();" oncomplete="menuComplete();" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

  <h:selectOneMenu id="whom" value="#{managedBeanState.person}" 
                   disabled="#{empty managedBeanState.selectedFoo}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{managedBean.persons)" var="person" itemLabel="#{person.name} " itemValue="#{person}" />
    <f:converter converterId="personConverter" />
    <p:ajax update="email" onstart="menuStart();" oncomplete="menuComplete();" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The converter class looks like this.

```
@FacesConverter(value = "fooConverter", forClass = com.examples.Foo.class)
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent c, String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) FacesContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getBean("sessionFactory");
        String[] idAndClassName = value.split(":|_");
        String className = idAndClassName[1];
        String id = idAndClassName[0];
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Class.forName(className), Long.parseLong(id));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error loading from value:" + value, e);
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent c, Object value) {
    if (value == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(value.toString())) {
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }

    return ((Foo) value).getId().toString() + ":" + value.getClass().getName();
}
}
```

My web.xml looks like this

```
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have checked BalusC [blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)  but setting PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING to false did not help. I also ran in debug mode and saw that getAsObject was indeed returning the object but it never calls the setter after that. So when the getter is called for the second drop down menu where it checks this disabled="#{empty managedBeanState.selectedFoo}"
it is always null.

Update: Created an [issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2384) ON JIRA

Comment: It look like that the `equals()` method of your `Foo` class is broken. But this should have resulted in the famous "Validation Error: Value Not Valid" error. Have you checked the server log and/or added a  `<h:message>` or `<h:messages>`?

Comment: What is the equals() method you are referring to? yes, I did try putting <h:message>, it just silently does nothing.

Comment: For temporarily, I have made the managedBean as request scope and managedBeanState as view scope and works good.